# Unable to convert string to JSON with json.loads

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
    print(payload_d)
    a = json.dumps(payload_d)
    print(a)
    b = json.loads(a)
    print(type(b))
    c = "{\"temp\":\"2\"}"
    d = json.loads(c)
    print(type(d))
```

Output

```
{"temp":"2"}
"{\"temp\":\"2\"}"
<class 'str'>
<class 'dict'>
```

variable b and d should ideally be dict. However I'm unable to convert variable b to dict.
As a test I copied content from variable b to c, which successfully converted the string to dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused about your sample data.

You start with:

```
>>> payload_d = '{"temp":"2"}'
```

`payload_d` isn't a Python data structure; it's a string. When you call:

```
>>> a = json.dumps(payload_d)
```

You end up with the JSON-encoded value of that string, which is:

```
"{\"temp\":\"2\"}"
```

When you call:

```
>>> b = json.loads(a)
```

You get back the original value of `payload_d` -- as you would expect -- which is just a string.

Comment: Thank you @larsks, do you have any suggestions how can I convert this string variable of "payload_d" to json? 
payload_d is just the variable in the code. I don't have control over the actual payload as it comes from aws Greengrass stream manager - client.read_messages.

Comment: `payload_d` is *already* valid JSON. You can *decode* it (`x = json.loads(payload_d)`), but it doesn't really make sense to "convert it to JSON".

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't make sense to "convert it to JSON". My end goal is to push this to a csv file. I'm not sure how I can achieve that without creating json.

Comment: Maybe I haven't been sufficiently clear, but `payload_d` is **already JSON**.That's why it doesn't make sense to to convert it.